# Change toggle button image Icon In Navigation Drawer right to left

Tags: android

I Want to change the navigation drawer toggle icon for close and open.

I downloaded the sample code from this link:

http://vardhan-justlikethat.blogspot.in/2014/02/android-slider-from-right-to-left.html

But there is no method call when navigation drawer closed.
I required to change that toggle button with some other image,

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

DrawerListener:

```
DrawerListener drawerListener = new DrawerListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
        drawerHandleImage.setImageResource(R.id.closed);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
        drawerHandleImage.setImageResource(R.id.opened);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) { }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) { }

};
```

Set the listener to your DrawerLayout:

```
drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

in res/drawable-hdpi/ ,res/drawable-mdpi/ , res/drawable-xhdpi/ and res/drawable-xxhdpi/ you have ic_drawer.png change that with your image

Comment: But I want to set the two image,When drawer open set the drawer_open.png and when it closed it set the drawer_closed.png